# How to customize metrics in sonar?

Tags: customization, sonarqube, metric

I'm a new user of sonar. Now I need to customize metrics, but I didn't find the related documentation. If I have to coding a plugin? I do the same with http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Getting+Started, but I failed. There is no difference at the localhost:9000/profiles.

Comment: What do you mean by "customize" metrics? Add new metrics? Or what?

Answer (score 3):

For proper integration into the Sonar build you need to write plugin:

- http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Developing+Plugins

If you just want to add some additional adhoc metrics to your dashboard,
an option is to use manual measures:

- http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Manual+Measures

There's a REST API available to creating and posting manual metric values:

- http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392169

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I want to write a plugin but I can't use maven because of the limitation from our company. I downloaded sonar-artifact-size-plugin-0.3.jar and the source of it. I installed the plugin then it worked well. While I built the source to a test.jar and installed test.jar. The outcome of analysis showed no data. I read the source but I did't find the code to calculate the value of metric. Does it use this file "artifactSizeWidget.erb" to calculate it? I just know it's a file of ruby while I have't learn ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Metric using Manual Metrics through the sonar GUI (I think you need admin rights).
Manual metrics can be updated through the GUI too.

If your plugin built OK but there are no numbers appearing: you must also run an analysis to populate the new Metrics with some Measures.